# How should I parse these DateTime strings?

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I have two formats of a date: `11-Apr-2018` & `11-04-2018`.

For `11-04-2018` I use `"dd-MM-yyyy"` with DateTime.TryParseExact with success.

For `11-Apr-2018` I use `"dd-MMM-yyyy"` but the result is `01/01/2018`.

Which format should I try parse against for the date value `11-Apr-2018`?

Here is my code:

```
CultureInfo enZA = new CultureInfo("en-ZA");
var formatStrings = new string[] { "yyyy-MM-dd", "dd-MMM-yyyy" };
DateTime formattedDate;
DateTime.TryParseExact(dateToFormat, 
                       formatStrings, 
                       enZA, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, 
                       out formattedDate);
```

Comment: it converts for me, no code, cant reproduce your issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853(v=vs.110).aspx) where you can specify *several formats*:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
  valueToParse,
  new string[] { 
    "d-MM-yyyy",     // try this first
    "d-MMM-yyyy" },  // on failure try this next
  CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
  DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);
```

For instance

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "11-04-2018",
    "11-Apr-2018",
  };

  var result = tests
    .Select(test => DateTime
      .ParseExact(test,
                  new string[] { "d-MM-yyyy", "d-MMM-yyyy" },
                  CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"),
                  DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal))
    .Select(date => date.ToString("dd : MM : yyyy"));

 Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Outcome:

```
 11 : 04 : 2018
 11 : 04 : 2018
```

Answer (score 0):

`dd-MMM-yyyy` should be correct

```
var foo =  DateTime.Now;
foo.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

worked for me, I use the tostring maybe that is behaving differently to the [TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?